# How can I combine function calls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently developing a WebSocket. For that purpose I've created a JavaScript class. In this class I've 2 methods: `subscribe()` and `bind()`. The first method subscribes to a channel and the next one should listen to it.

But when I call my methods this way:

```
let socket = new CustomWebSocket();

socket.subscribe("my-channel").bind("my-event", function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I'm getting an error message in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: socket.subscribe(...).bind is not a function
```

This is how I wrote my functions inside my `CustomWebSocket` class:

```
subscribe(channelName) {
    let self = this;

    let subMsg = {
        type: "subscribe",
        channel: channelName
    };

    self.ws.send(JSON.stringify(subMsg));

    return channelName;
}

bind(eventName, callback) {
    let self = this;

    self.ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        let eventData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (eventData.type === "channelMessage") {
            callback(eventData.payload);
        }
    }
}
```

What did I wrong? It thought it can work this way...

Comment: `socket.subscribe("my-channel"); socket.bind();` - you don't have a fluent interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning `channelName;` from `subscribe`. So you're effectively trying to call `bind` on `channelName`.

To be able to call `bind` on the return value of `subscribe`, you need to return `self` or `this` from `subscribe`.